# convert ArrayList.toString() back to ArrayList in one call

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, tostring

I have a `toString()` representation of an `ArrayList`.

Copying the `toString()` value to clipboard, I want to copy it back into my IDE editor, and create the `ArrayList` instance in one line.  In fact, what I'm really doing is this:

- my ArrayList.toString() has data I need to setup a unit test.
- I want to copy this ArrayList.toString() into my editor to build a test against this edge case
- I don't want to parse anything by hand

My input looks like this:

```
[15.82, 15.870000000000001, 15.92, 16.32, 16.32, 16.32, 16.32, 17.05, 17.05, 17.05, 17.05, 18.29, 18.29, 19.16]
```

The following do not work:

- `Arrays.asList()`
- google collections `Lists.newArrayList()`

Suggestions?

Comment: Can you detail why Arrays.asList(15.82, 15.870000000000001, 15.92, 16.32, 16.32, 16.32, 16.32, 17.05, 17.05, 17.05, 17.05, 18.29, 18.29, 19.16) was not able to provide you a correct list ?

Comment: i picked that one arbitrarily.  sorry you are right about this.  my testcase list was of strings:  "[x,y,z]"

Answer (score 25):

[Substring](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) the braces away, [split](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) it on `,` (comma and space) and finally feed it to `Arrays#asList()`.

```
 String s = "[15.82, 15.870000000000001, 15.92, 16.32, 16.32, 16.32, 16.32, 17.05, 17.05, 17.05, 17.05, 18.29, 18.29, 19.16]";
 List<String> list = Arrays.asList(s.substring(1, s.length() - 1).split(", "));
```

Note that this will work in your particular case, but not in all circumstances. You may for example have a list of strings of which at least one contains a subsequent comma and space. The split would then fail.

Comment: I think you want s.length()-1, as the character at the endIndex is not included in the substring

Comment: just a matter of personal preference, but I prefer not to parse and like the google splitter solution better.

Comment: Your choice. I just wanted to prove that it *works*. You namely mentioned that it "do not work". Since you already gave the answer using Google Collections yourself beforehand, I did not want to waste time to duplicate it.

Comment: thanks.  just to clarify - i was looking for the path of least resistance / fastest way as i just needed data for a unit test.  i agree w/ parsing i could have done it...but i really wanted how can i copy ArrayList.toString() straight into my test case and have it work w/ no additional mod's.  i added my google coll solution as i came up w/ it a minute after posting.  thx again

Comment: Thanx BalusC . It helped very much.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking the `toString()` of any objects does not contain information to reproduce the original object without any further information.

In your specific case the example could be produced by many different `ArrayList` instances  (as well as pretty much all other `List` implementations which have identical `toString()`) implementations.

As an extreme example, think of an `ArrayList` that contains a single element which is the `String` with the content `15.82, 15.870000000000001, 15.92, 16.32, 16.32, 16.32, 16.32, 17.05, 17.05, 17.05, 17.05, 18.29, 18.29, 19.16`. That `ArrayList` would produce the exact same output as your original `ArrayList`. And since two different inputs produce the same output, there's no way this function can be reversed without additional information.

If, however, we have additional information, such as the content type of the original `ArrayList`, then it becomes possible in some cases. If we know that all elements of the `List` were of type `Double`, then it's actually pretty easy:

```
public static List<Double> stringToList(final String input) {
    String[] elements = input.substring(1, input.length() - 1).split(", ");
    List<Double> result = new ArrayList<Double>(elements.length);
    for (String item : elements) {
        result.add(Double.valueOf(item));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Granted, it's not a one-liner, but it's not too bad.

Answer (score 1):

this works, but perhaps someone has something more elegant?

```
    List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList(Splitter.on(",").omitEmptyStrings().split("JUN10, SEP10, DEC10, MAR11, JUN11, SEP11, DEC11, MAR12, JUN12, SEP12, DEC12, MAR13, DEC13, DEC14"));
    assertEquals(14, list.size());
```

Comment: had to remove the brackets from beginning and ending ArrayList.toString()

Comment: Looks like you are using Spltter from guava-libraries

Answer (score 0):

> I want to copy this
>   ArrayList.toString() into my editor to
>   build a test against this edge case

If at all you are copying, can't you just copy values omitting the square brackets and call an

```
Arrays.asList(...) ?
```

Comment: yep - i amended.  sorry.  values of type Number work fine; but what about when your list has string elements?

Comment: @dotnetnewbie: String elements will ony ever work if none of the String elements contains the substring `", "`.

Comment: the point of he exercise is to copy and paste into unit test and get unit test working w/ least path of resistance assuming you have a ArrayList.toString() that you can copy to clipboard from IDE

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for a copy paste solution,

```
    Arrays.asList(15.82, 15.870000000000001, 15.92, 16.32, 16.32, 16.32, 16.32, 17.05, 17.05, 17.05, 17.05, 18.29, 18.29, 19.16);
```

i.e. delete the quotes and square brackets before trying to put it into asList(). That should give you a List which you could easily use to create a new ArrayList.

If the data are more complicated than doubles, you may have to find a way to parse them.

Comment: P.S. data is the singular form of data.

Comment: Hi ILMTitan, I like this, but it doesn't work when the List has String elements ie "[x,y,z]"

Answer (score 0):

The "must be one line" requirement pretty much ensures that you're going to get some ugly mess of chained API calls unless you write a helper method to encapsulate things.

It's kind of ugly, but similar to dotnetnewbie's approach:

```
List<String> result = Arrays.asList(listString.substring(1, listString.length()-1).split(",\\s*"));
```

It's off the cuff so I'm sure that can be cleaned up a fair bit.

A more elegant and easier to read approach would definitely be to either break it out over a couple of lines or refactor to a helper method in your test case (or a Util class) that you can call with your string and have it return the output that you'd like.